# Comparison of full text search engine - Lucene, Sphinx, Postgresql, MySQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, full-text-search, lucene, sphinx

I'm building a Django site and I am looking for a search engine.

A few candidates:

- Lucene/Lucene with Compass/Solr
- Sphinx
- Postgresql built-in full text search
- MySQl built-in full text search

Selection criteria:

- result relevance and ranking
- searching and indexing speed
- ease of use and ease of integration with Django
- resource requirements - site will be hosted on a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server), so ideally the search engine wouldn't require a lot of RAM and CPU
- scalability
- extra features such as "did you mean?", related searches, etc

Anyone who has had experience with the search engines above, or other engines not in the list -- I would love to hear your opinions.

EDIT: As for indexing needs, as users keep entering data into the site, those data would need to be indexed continuously. It doesn't have to be real time, but ideally new data would show up in index with no more than 15 - 30 minutes delay

Comment: 2¢: MySQL fulltext search and transactions are (presently) mutually exclusive.  MySQL fulltext indexes require the MyISAM table type, which doesn't support transactions.  (As opposed to the InnoDB table type which supports transactions, but not fulltext indexes.)

Comment: PostgreSQL full-text search, `Tsearch` *does not* support phrase search. However, it's on the TODO list http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/FTS_Todo.

Comment: Anyone looking at this for Django should checkout the haystack app. http://haystacksearch.org/

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql

Comment: @CarlG , Just for everybody's reference. MySQL 5.6+ has Full text search support with innodb engine

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Good to see someone's chimed in about Lucene - because I've no idea about that.

Sphinx, on the other hand, I know quite well, so let's see if I can be of some help.

- Result relevance ranking is the default. You can set up your own sorting should you wish, and give specific fields higher weightings.
- Indexing speed is super-fast, because it talks directly to the database. Any slowness will come from complex SQL queries and un-indexed foreign keys and other such problems. I've never noticed any slowness in searching either.
- I'm a Rails guy, so I've no idea how easy it is to implement with Django. There is a Python API that comes with the Sphinx source though.
- The search service daemon (searchd) is pretty low on memory usage - and you can set limits on [how much memory](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.8.html#conf-mem-limit) the indexer process uses too.
- Scalability is where my knowledge is more sketchy - but it's easy enough to copy index files to multiple machines and run several searchd daemons. The general impression I get from others though is that it's pretty damn good under high load, so scaling it out across multiple machines isn't something that needs to be dealt with.
- There's no support for 'did-you-mean', etc - although these can be done with other tools easily enough. Sphinx does stem words though using dictionaries, so 'driving' and 'drive' (for example) would be considered the same in searches.
- Sphinx doesn't allow partial index updates for field data though. The common approach to this is to maintain a delta index with all the recent changes, and re-index this after every change (and those new results appear within a second or two). Because of the small amount of data, this can take a matter of seconds. You will still need to re-index the main dataset regularly though (although how regularly depends on the volatility of your data - every day? every hour?). The fast indexing speeds keep this all pretty painless though.

I've no idea how applicable to your situation this is, but [Evan Weaver compared a few of the common Rails search options](http://blog.evanweaver.com/articles/2008/03/17/rails-search-benchmarks/) (Sphinx, Ferret (a port of Lucene for Ruby) and Solr), running some benchmarks. Could be useful, I guess.

I've not plumbed the depths of MySQL's full-text search, but I know it doesn't compete speed-wise nor feature-wise with Sphinx, Lucene or Solr.

Comment: Sphinx does allow you to update individual attributes of items in current indexes, but not remove/update full records.

Comment: sphinx RT allows you to do partial updates/removals. it is in early stage but already [almost] works. http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=rt_tutorial

Comment: [Here is an answer on Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284083/choosing-a-stand-alone-full-text-search-server-sphinx-or-solr) that is a good pair to this answer on Sphinx

Comment: Nothing can match Sphinx for speed, so if speed is your number one concern then Sphinx is the option to go for. Nice post

Comment: Sphinx 2.3.2 Beta has now a feature called 'CALL SUGGEST' which can be used to implement 'did you mean ?'
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/devel.html#sphinxql-call-suggest

Answer (score 83):

I don't know Sphinx, but as for Lucene vs a database full-text search, I think that Lucene performance is unmatched. You should be able to do almost *any* search in less than 10 ms, no matter how many records you have to search, provided that you have set up your Lucene index correctly.

Here comes the biggest hurdle though: personally, I think integrating Lucene in your project is not *easy*. Sure, it is not too hard to set it up so you can do some basic search, but if you want to get the most out of it, with optimal performance, then you definitely need a good book about Lucene.

As for CPU & RAM requirements, performing a search in Lucene doesn't task your CPU too much, though indexing your data is, although you don't do that too often (maybe once or twice a day), so that isn't much of a hurdle.

It doesn't answer all of your questions but in short, if you have a lot of data to search, and you want great performance, then I think Lucene is definitely the way to go. If you're not going to have that much data to search, then you might as well go for a database full-text search. Setting up a MySQL full-text search is definitely easier in my book.

Comment: Compare to sphinx , lucence is tooo slow and bulky. I had used both in my project and i finally sticked to sphinx. Lucence is in java , and it takes a lot more CPU and RAM than Sphinx.

Comment: I have to disagree here. Lucene is lightning fast IF you build a correct index. You can basically do an advanced query over millions of records in just a couple of milliseconds. You just need to know what you are doing. And Lucene is in java... your point being? There's also .NET port, Lucene.NET btw.

Comment: but you clearly stated that you don't use sphinx, and v3sson has used both.

Comment: how can you state that lucene's performance is unmatched in the same sentence that you state you haven't used sphinx?

Comment: Valid questions. I never said that Lucene is faster than Sphinx, I mentioned that Lucene vs a database full-text search is unmatched. And it is. No question about that. Lucene is based upon an inverted index. Now I don't know Sphinx, as mentioned before, but if it also uses an inverted index or a similar indexing method then it is possible that they are equally performing. Stating that Lucene, compared to Sphinx, would be 'tooo slow and bulky' is not based upon facts. Especially not when it is only said that Lucene is in 'Java', which is just a ridiculous non-issue in terms of performance.

Comment: Making the assumption that Lucene is slow because its in Java is ridiculous. Java is not slow, the hotspot vm is a work of art and in most cases your correctly written app will run faster that a c application. I my experience Lucene is light weight, fast albeit a bit fiddly.

Comment: V3ss0n did not say that, in his opinion, Lucene is slow because it is Java. He said that it is Java and it "takes a lot more CPU and RAM than Sphinx".

Comment: Lucene is rather slow doing wildcard queries.

Comment: None of these comments about "fast" or "memory usage" are useful without some numbers. What server? 2 or 64 cores? Atom or Xeon? 2GB or 64GB of Ram? How many documents? What data size?

Comment: It was rather slow for us, giving unacceptable search duration in production usage well below that Postgresql was able to do with ilike. Maybe it was wrongly setup as none of us had experience with it. But anyway this means the thing requires attention and respect to work with.

Answer (score 63):

## [Apache *Solr*](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

---

Apart from answering OP's queries, Let me throw some insights on ***Apache Solr*** from **simple introduction** to **detailed installation** and **implementation**.

> ## Simple Introduction

---

> *Anyone who has had experience with the search engines above, or other
>   engines not in the list -- I would love to hear your opinions.*

**Solr** shouldn't be used to solve real-time problems. For search engines, **Solr** is pretty much game and works *flawlessly*.

**Solr** works fine on High Traffic web-applications (*I read somewhere that it is not suited for this, but I am backing up that statement*). It utilizes the RAM, not the CPU.

> - result relevance and ranking

The **boost** helps you rank your results show up on top. Say, you're trying to search for a name *john* in the fields *firstname* and *lastname*, and you want to give relevancy to the *firstname* field, then you need to **boost** up the *firstname* field as shown.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=firstname:john^2&lastname:john
```

As you can see, *firstname* field is **boosted** up with a score of 2.

More on [SolrRelevancy](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ)

> - searching and indexing speed

The speed is unbelievably fast and no compromise on that. The reason I moved to **Solr**.

Regarding the indexing speed, **Solr** can also handle **JOINS** from your database tables. A higher and complex **JOIN** do affect the indexing speed. However, an enormous **RAM** config can easily tackle this situation.

The higher the RAM, The faster the indexing speed of Solr is.

> - ease of use and ease of integration with Django

Never attempted to integrate **Solr** and **Django**, however you can achieve to do that with [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/). I found some interesting [article](http://www.alexanderinteractive.com/blog/2012/08/getting-started-with-solr-and-django/) on the same and here's the [github](https://github.com/broderboy/django-solr-demo) for it.

> - resource requirements - site will be hosted on a VPS, so ideally the  search engine wouldn't require a lot of RAM and CPU

**Solr** breeds on RAM, so if the RAM is high, you don't to have to worry about **Solr**.

**Solr's** RAM usage shoots up on full-indexing if you have some billion records, you could smartly make use of Delta imports to tackle this situation. As explained, **Solr** *is only a near real-time solution*.

> - scalability

**Solr** is highly scalable. Have a look on [SolrCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud).
Some key features of it.

- Shards (or sharding is the concept of distributing the index among multiple machines, say if your index has grown too large)
- Load Balancing (if [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) is used with Solr cloud it automatically takes care of load-balancing using it's Round-Robin mechanism)
- [Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch)
- High Availability

> - extra features such as "did you mean?", related searches, etc

For the above scenario, you could use the [SpellCheckComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent) that is packed up with **Solr**. There are a lot other features, The [SnowballPorterFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/3_6_1/org/apache/solr/analysis/SnowballPorterFilterFactory.html) helps to retrieve records say if you typed, *books* instead of *book*, you will be presented with results related to *book*.

---

This answer broadly focuses on **Apache Solr** & **MySQL**.  Django is out of scope.

Assuming that you are under LINUX environment, you could proceed to this article further. (mine was an Ubuntu 14.04 version)

> ## Detailed Installation

### Getting Started

Download **Apache Solr** from [here](http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/lucene/solr/4.8.1/). That would be version is **4.8.1**. You could download new versions, I found this stable.

After downloading the archive , extract it to a folder of your choice. 
Say ..  `Downloads` or whatever.. So it will look like `Downloads/solr-4.8.1/`

On your prompt..  Navigate inside the directory

`shankar@shankar-lenovo: cd Downloads/solr-4.8.1`

So now you are here ..

`shankar@shankar-lenovo: ~/Downloads/solr-4.8.1$`

### Start the Jetty Application Server

**Jetty** is available inside the examples folder of the `solr-4.8.1` directory , so navigate inside that and start the Jetty Application Server.

`shankar@shankar-lenovo:~/Downloads/solr-4.8.1/example$ java -jar start.jar`

Now , do not close the terminal , minimize it and let it stay aside.

> ( TIP : Use & after start.jar to make the Jetty Server run in the
>   background )

To check if **Apache Solr** runs successfully, visit this URL on the browser. http://localhost:8983/solr

### Running Jetty on custom Port

It runs on the port 8983 as default. You could change the port either here or directly inside the `jetty.xml` file.

`java -Djetty.port=9091 -jar start.jar`

### Download the JConnector

This JAR file acts as a bridge between **MySQL** and JDBC , Download the Platform Independent Version [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

After downloading it, extract the folder and copy the`mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar` and paste it to the **lib** directory.

`shankar@shankar-lenovo:~/Downloads/solr-4.8.1/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib`

### Creating the MySQL table to be linked to Apache Solr

To put **Solr** to use, You need to have some tables and data to search for. For that, we will use **MySQL** for creating a table and pushing some random names and then we could use **Solr** to connect to **MySQL** and index that table and it's entries.

#### 1.Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE test_solr_mysql
 (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  created TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```

#### 2.Populate the above table

```
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Jean');
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Jack');
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Jason');
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Vego');
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Grunt');
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Jasper');
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Fred');
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Jenna');
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Rebecca');
INSERT INTO `test_solr_mysql` (`name`) VALUES ('Roland');
```

### Getting inside the core and adding the lib directives

#### 1.Navigate to

```
shankar@shankar-lenovo: ~/Downloads/solr-4.8.1/example/solr/collection1/conf
```

#### 2.Modifying the solrconfig.xml

Add these two directives to this file..

```
  <lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```

Now add the **DIH** (Data Import Handler)

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" 
  class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

#### 3.Create the db-data-config.xml file

If the file exists then ignore, add these lines to that file. As you can see the first line, you need to provide the credentials of your **MySQL** database. The Database name, username and password.

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourdbname" user="dbuser" password="dbpass"/>
    <document>
   <entity name="test_solr" query="select CONCAT('test_solr-',id) as rid,name from test_solr_mysql WHERE '${dataimporter.request.clean}' != 'false'
      OR `created` > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'" >
    <field name="id" column="rid" />
    <field name="solr_name" column="name" />
    </entity>
   </document>
</dataConfig>
```

> ( TIP : You can have any number of entities but watch out for id field,
>   if they are same then indexing will skipped. )

#### 4.Modify the schema.xml file

Add this to your **schema.xml** as shown..

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<field name="solr_name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

> ## Implementation

### Indexing

This is where the real deal is. You need to do the indexing of data from **MySQL** to **Solr** inorder to make use of Solr Queries.

#### Step 1: Go to Solr Admin Panel

Hit the URL http://localhost:8983/solr on your browser. The screen opens like this.

[image: This is the main Apache Solr Administration Panel]

As the marker indicates, go to **Logging** inorder to check if any of the above configuration has led to errors.

#### Step 2: Check your Logs

Ok so now you are here, As you can there are a lot of yellow messages (WARNINGS). Make sure you don't have error messages marked in red. Earlier, on our configuration we had added a select query on our **db-data-config.xml**, say if there were any errors on that query, it would have shown up here.

[image: This is the logging section of your Apache Solr engine]

Fine, no errors. We are good to go. Let's choose **collection1** from the list as depicted and select **Dataimport**

#### Step 3: DIH (Data Import Handler)

Using the DIH, you will be connecting to **MySQL** from **Solr** through the configuration file **db-data-config.xml** from the **Solr** interface and retrieve the 10 records from the database which gets indexed onto **Solr**.

To do that, Choose **full-import** , and check the options *Clean* and *Commit*. Now click **Execute** as shown.

Alternatively, you could use a direct **full-import** query like this too..

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/dataimport?command=full-import&commit=true
```

[image: The Data Import Handler]

After you clicked **Execute**, **Solr** begins to index the records, if there were any errors, it would say **Indexing Failed** and you have to go back to the **Logging** section to see what has gone wrong.

Assuming there are no errors with this configuration and if the indexing is successfully complete., you would get this notification.

[image: Indexing Success]

#### Step 4: Running Solr Queries

Seems like everything went well, now you could use **Solr** Queries to query the data that was indexed. Click the **Query** on the left and then press **Execute** button on the bottom.

You will see the indexed records as shown.

The corresponding **Solr** query for listing all the records is

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true
```

[image: The indexed data]

Well, there goes all 10 indexed records. Say, we need only names starting with **Ja** , in this case, you need to target the column name `solr_name`, Hence your query goes like this.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=solr_name:Ja*&wt=json&indent=true
```

[image: The JSON data starting with Ja*]

That's how you write **Solr** Queries. To read more about it, Check this beautiful [article](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/queryparsersyntax.html).

Comment: @Downvoter, feel free to comment or edit this answer and reasoning for the downvote will help others too.

Comment: this is one of the most comprehensive and well organized  posts I've seen on SO. Awesome job.

Answer (score 60):

I am surprised that there isn't more information posted about Solr. Solr is quite similar to Sphinx but has more advanced features (AFAIK as I haven't used Sphinx -- only read about it).

The answer at the link below details a few things about Sphinx which also applies to Solr.
[Comparison of full text search engine - Lucene, Sphinx, Postgresql, MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/pros-cons-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-full-text-searc/737931#737931)

Solr also provides the following additional features:

1. Supports replication
2. Multiple cores (think of these as separate databases with their own configuration and own indexes)
3. Boolean searches
4. Highlighting of keywords (fairly easy to do in application code if you have regex-fu; however, why not let a specialized tool do a better job for you)
5. Update index via XML or delimited file
6. Communicate with the search server via HTTP (it can even return Json, Native PHP/Ruby/Python)
7. PDF, Word document indexing
8. Dynamic fields
9. Facets
10. Aggregate fields
11. Stop words, synonyms, etc.
12. More Like this...
13. Index directly from the database with custom queries
14. Auto-suggest
15. Cache Autowarming
16. Fast indexing (compare to MySQL full-text search indexing times) -- Lucene uses a binary inverted index format.
17. Boosting (custom rules for increasing relevance of a particular keyword or phrase, etc.)
18. Fielded searches (if a search user knows the field he/she wants to search, they narrow down their search by typing the field, then the value, and ONLY that field is searched rather than everything -- much better user experience)

BTW, there are tons more features; however, I've listed just the features that I have actually used in production. BTW, out of the box, MySQL supports #1, #3, and #11 (limited) on the list above. For the features you are looking for, a relational database isn't going to cut it. I'd eliminate those straight away.

Also, another benefit is that Solr (well, Lucene actually) is a document database (e.g. NoSQL) so many of the benefits of any other document database can be realized with Solr. In other words, you can use it for more than just search (i.e. Performance). Get creative with it :)

Comment: Sphinx too about
    Supports replication
    Multiple cores 
    Boolean searches
    Highlighting of keywords 
    Update index via XML -or delimited file-
    PDF, Word document indexing (via xml)
    Facets
    Stop words, synonyms, etc.
    Index directly from the database with custom queries
    Auto-suggest
    Fast indexing
    Boosting 
    Fielded searches
About
    Dynamic fields 
    Aggregate fields
    Cache Autowarming
I just don't know

Answer (score 30):

I'm looking at PostgreSQL full-text search right now, and it has all the right features of a modern search engine, really good extended character and multilingual support, nice tight integration with text fields in the database.

But it doesn't have user-friendly search operators like + or AND (uses & | !) and I'm not thrilled with how it works on their documentation site.  While it has bolding  of match terms in the results snippets, the default algorithm for which match terms is not great. Also, if you want to index rtf, PDF, MS Office, you have to find and integrate a file format converter.

OTOH, it's way better than the MySQL text search, which doesn't even index words of three letters or fewer.  It's the default for the MediaWiki search, and I really think it's no good for end-users: http://www.searchtools.com/analysis/mediawiki-search/

**In all cases I've seen, Lucene/Solr and Sphinx are really great**.  They're solid code and have evolved with significant improvements in usability, so the tools are all there to make search that satisfies almost everyone.

for SHAILI - SOLR includes the Lucene search code library and has the components to be a nice stand-alone search engine.

Comment: I believe that by PostgreSQL full-text search you're referring to `Tsearch`.  But Tsearch *does not* support phrase search.  It's still on their TODO list http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/FTS_Todo.

Comment: Just done a bunch of testing on Postgres 9.0 full text search; was disappointed to find that French text isn't matched if the user forgets to get all the accents right. Matching of word forms is patchy - for example, in English "say" doesn't match text containing "said". Overall fairly impressive though for an integrated feature across the languages tested (en, fr, ru).

Comment: @romkyns: you need to install an unaccent dictionary to strip them out.

Comment: "OTOH, it's way better than the MySQL text search, which doesn't even index words of three letters or fewer." That's not a built-in restriction of MySQL -- it's whatever you set in the config file.  If you want to index one-letter words, just change one value in the config.

Comment: For phrase searches see the "synonym" dictionary feature. That's an odd name for a feature which allows phrase searches to work well, but I had not trouble setting up a dictionary of legal terms that way.

Comment: It's worrying that people are giving comparisons on databases they haven't fully explored yet. MySQL **CAN** index words with three characters or fewer - you just have to configure it properly.

Answer (score 25):

Just my two cents to this very old question. I would highly recommend taking a look at [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

> Elasticsearch is a search server based on Lucene. It provides a distributed, multitenant-capable full-text search engine with a RESTful web interface and schema-free JSON documents. Elasticsearch is developed in Java and is released as open source under the terms of the Apache License.

The advantages over other FTS (full text search) Engines are:

- RESTful interface
- Better scalability
- Large community
- Built by Lucene
  developers
- Extensive documentation
- [There are many](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/integrations.html) open source libraries available (including Django)

We are using this search engine at our project and very happy with it.

Answer (score 10):

SearchTools-Avi said "MySQL text search, which doesn't even index words of three letters or fewer."

FYIs, The MySQL fulltext min word length is adjustable since *at least* MySQL 5.0. Google 'mysql fulltext min length' for simple instructions.

That said, MySQL fulltext has limitations: for one, it gets slow to update once you reach a million records or so, ...

Answer (score 2):

I would add [mnoGoSearch](http://www.mnogosearch.org/) to the list. Extremely performant and flexible solution, which works as Google : indexer fetches data from multiple sites, You could use basic criterias, or invent Your own hooks to have maximal search quality. Also it could fetch the data directly from the database.

The solution is not so known today, but it feets maximum needs. You could compile and install it or on standalone server, or even on Your principal server, it doesn't need so much ressources as Solr, as it's written in C and runs perfectly even on small servers.

In the beginning You need to compile it Yourself, so it requires some knowledge. I made a tiny [script](https://github.com/fedir/mnogosearch-typo3/blob/master/installation-debian.sh) for Debian, which could help. Any adjustments are welcome.

As You are using Django framework, You could use or PHP client in the middle, or find a solution in Python, I saw [some](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/xml-sig/2002-September/008623.html) [articles](http://blog.garambrogne.net/post/2004/04/15/14-mnogosearch-et-python).

And, of course mnoGoSearch is open source, GNU GPL.

Answer (score 2):

We just switched from Elasticsearch to Postgres Full Text. Since we have already used Postgres, we now save ourselves the hassle of keeping the index up to date.
But this only affects the full text search. There are, however, use cases where Elasicsearch is significantly better. Maybe facets or something like that.