# php based full text search of MySQL data?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, full-text-search

If this is true:

- [4000% Performance Increase By Sorting In PHP Rather Than MySQL](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/3/23/digg-4000-performance-increase-by-sorting-in-php-rather-than.html)

How can one full text search with PHP only?  In other words, how can the search actually be processed in PHP while the data stays in MySQL?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's an example of a PHP full text search engine: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.lucene.intro.html

Comment: @Calle does that search web pages or database data?  Thanks!

Comment: 4000% faster may not make it a preferred option. in most php\mysql speed is not going to be an issue. have you benchmarked your search? is it to slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely several ways to do this (although I can not say anything on the 4000%).  What has came up most often is using something like sphinx or lucene.

http://sphinxsearch.com/files/talks/sphinx-nyphp_meetup-2011.pdf

Looking through SO there are a few questions that touched on the concept.
[php mysql fulltext search: lucene, sphinx, or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942810/php-mysql-fulltext-search-lucene-sphinx-or)
some good information - [Comparison of full text search engine - Lucene, Sphinx, Postgresql, MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql)

In most cases though performance searching in mySQL can be improved with indexes.
Indexing Basic MySQL Queries - http://hackmysql.com/case1