# Ruby alternative for Lucene

Tags: java, ruby, lucene

I have heard about Lucene a lot, that it's one of the best search engine libraries in Java.  Is there any similar (as powerful) library for Ruby?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, there's [Ferret](http://ferret.davebalmain.com/trac), which is a port of Lucene to Ruby. Also, Lucene is very easy to use from [JRuby](http://jruby.org), if that's an option for you.

Depending on your needs, you might also want to take a look at [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), which is a higher-level front-end built on Lucene. There is a Ruby interface, [solr-ruby](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/solr-ruby), that interacts with Solr via HTTP.

Comment: A few people have recommended [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.io) to me, which builds upon RSolr, but I have not personally tried it.

Answer (score 6):

[Ferret](http://ferret.davebalmain.com/trac) is what you're looking for:

*"Ferret is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written for Ruby. It is inspired by Apache Lucene Java project."*

Comment: Well you surely can put the high-performance in question. I find it deadly slow.

Comment: Can you share any performance numbers? Like x seconds to return a search over y documents/rows/whatever?

Comment: I have no personal experience with Ferret, but judging by what I've read and this page: http://ferret.davebalmain.com/trac/wiki/MyFirstBenchmark it used to be slow but is now comparable with Java Lucene. There are performance numbers on that page. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

I would try one of them in combination with [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Thinking Sphinx
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/rails3.html

Riddle
http://riddle.freelancing-gods.com/

http://blog.evanweaver.com/files/doc/fauna/ultrasphinx/files/README.html

Answer (score 1):

CLucene is a cross-platform C++ port of Lucene. It can be wrapped and used also from every high-level language (there are also a few legacy Swift projects you could start with). See:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene

http://clucene.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=clucene/clucene;a=summary

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, in most cases, ferret is not what you're looking for, it's got recurring issues with re-indexing speed, index corruption and  segfaults on the server.  I think most people are going to SOLR, sphinx, and Xapian.  I recall seeing some Tsearch / postgres apps mentioned, Tsearch seems to be a industrial-strength solution

Take a look here

[Full Text Searching with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132284/full-text-searching-with-rails)