# How to search in database by like query in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

i am using rails and mongo db as database
simply i want to search 
I have a field name role
Now i send the search item in

```
params[:role]
params[:name]
```

Now i have the model User
now what could be my query to search the data in the User model like params[:name]
I did like

```
 @role = params[:role]
    @name = params[:name] 
     @data = User.{where(:role => @role)}.where("description LIKE (?)",
    "%#   {@name}%").desc(:created_at).
    excludes(:id    => current_user.id)
```

Above query is just analysis. I mean to say it should like in therotical but i didnt get id.

Comment: Did you even tried to search this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326662/search-through-sentences

Comment: Can u edit my question. I am messed up. It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? (from my head...)

```
 @role = params[:role]
 @name = params[:name] 
 @users = User.where(:role => @role)
 @data = @users.where(users[:description].matches("%#{@name}%")).order("created_at desc").excludes(:id=> current_user.id)
```

Comment: what is users here? I dont understand. and (:description) is the field  name of users collection?

Comment: `users[:description].matches("%#{@name}%")` is the AREL-version of `"description LIKE (?)"`. I took those names from your commands, you you should know what they actually stand for :)

Comment: If i want to match with other field also like field :email :address with @ name then what should i do?