# Search mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

I want to implement a powerful search engine for my ecommerce application. im using php and mysql as database. Can anyone guide me how to proceed? Is the FULL TEXT feature of MYSQL good for a large volume of data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the MySQL Full text engine is a really poor choice.

Firstly, the number of parameters to tweak the search is almost 0.

Secondly, from my experiencem it doesn't scale.

You might consider using

- [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/)
- [Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html)

Lucene is said to be the industry standard project. They have [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) if you want to have a separate architecture.

They are far more advanced and perform better.

Answer (score 0):

**[This should get you started](http://www.weberdev.com/ViewArticle/PHP:-A-simple-MySQL-search)**, however you will have to *modify or expand* on the idea.

For the second part of your question, have a look at:

**[Pros & Cons of Full Text Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/pros-cons-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-full-text-searc)**

Answer (score 0):

Recently, for an app handling a huge amount of data,  we have given up both MySQL FULL TEXT and Lucene to switch on PostgreSQL which has a much more powerful native FULL TEXT engine. At least, it was what the results of our investigations said.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Zend_Lucene from Zend_Framework and a new feature for mysql full text search [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?107,98685,98685)