# How Would I Allow Users To Search MySql Database With Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, search-engine

i have looked on google,yahoo,bing i used these keywords

```
allow people to search my database
allow people to search my database PhP,MySql
allow people to search my database PhP,MySql/MySQLi
Php,MySql Database Search script
```

and alot more key words can some one point me in the right direction for a PHP,MySQL database search

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search mysql database using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340315/search-mysql-database-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an interface that would allow people to search the database - that means a HTML form that would be processed by some PHP script that would query the database and then return/display the results.

Comment: thank you i finaly did it now i need Php Pagination i have made a new question its over at http://tinyurl.com/bvzdq9n

Answer (score 0):

On my website, I wrote this script, it will search a database and display the results, along with pagination:
http://phpsnips.com/94/Search-Database#.UNy6HddQC0w