# What is the advantage of Lucene searching and indexing?

Tags: algorithm, lucene, quick-search

I want to know , What is the advantage of Lucene searching and indexing ?

Is searching with Lucene as fast as other searching algorithm like Quick Search?
What about indexing ?

I want to know more about advantage of Lucene rather that others .

thanks .

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want us to compare two incomparable things.
[Quick Search](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node19.html) is a string search algorithm, meant to find a string in a long text document.

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is a search *library*, meant to index and search a collection of documents, ranking the results as it goes.

A more reasonable comparison is of Lucene versus other search libraries. [Here's one such comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/pros-cons-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-full-text-searc).

If you provide some background about your intended application, the SO community may be able to recommend, first an approach, and then a specific software tool inside that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should google inverted index and search engines to get a better idea of Lucene.

Lucene is a very popular search engine library, with an active community and a host of real world implementations (battle tested).If you are looking to build a search engine, Lucene (or Solr - which is built around Lucene) should be at the top of your list.