# Lucene vs MySQL MyISAM

Tags: mysql, lucene, myisam

Now, we are using lucene to do search. However, compared with lucene, could we use Mysql MyISAM instead.

What are benefits to use them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638671/search-engine-lucene-vs-database-search

Comment: thanks, full text search and index are support for both lucene and myISM, I think. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Lucene you will be able to create (only) a Full-Text index who will perform better with full-text queries compared. Keep in mind that it is only a Full-text search and not a fully featured DBMS.

Another search engine is [Xapian](http://xapian.org/), or wrapped into an [application](http://xapian.org/docs/omega/overview.html). I don't have personal experience with it, but from what I have heard it is perfect to search trough huge amounts of information.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bad idea to use MyIsam as you can't do foreign key relations within your index. It will also be slower than Lucene for searching text fields.

Comment: I won't use neither lucene nor myISM for data identity. Innodb has well support for such thing. In term of full text search, I'd like to know which one is better support and which one have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM FullText search is not the most configurable.  Some changes require recompiling MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

It is also somewhat limited, especially if you want to FullText multiple fields (you can't say "field A has foo or field B has bar" within the fulltext query--you need a SQL OR).  Another limitation is the fixed 50% threshold for [natural language searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

I would guess that Lucene's FullText is much faster, since Lucene was built to perform these searches.  If your data is already in MySQL, you may want to try MyISAM.  If you just want to search, go with Lucene.  Lucene also will scale much easier than MySQL FullText.