# Do Lucene and Sphinx support prefix matching?

Tags: lucene, sphinx

If not how do you make this work with them and which is better?

e.g. when searching for "mi" i would like results with "microsoft" to potentially show up in a result even though there is no "keyword" like "mi" specifically.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/pros-cons-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-full-text-searc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and Yes.

Lucene has [PrefixQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/PrefixQuery.html):

```
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
for (String token : tokenize(queryString)) {
  query.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term(LABEL_FIELD_NAME, token)), Occur.MUST);
}
return query;
```

You can also use the Lucene [query parser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html) and define the prefix search by [using a wildcard](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches) `exam*`. The query parser syntax works if you want to deploy a separate [Lucene search server, Solr,](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)  that is called using a HTTP API

In Sphinx it seams you have to do the following:

1. Set [minimum prefix length](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-1.10.html#conf-min-prefix-len) to a value larger than 0
2. [Enable wildcard syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-1.10.html#conf-enable-star)
3. Generate a query string with a willdcard `exam*`

Comment: I've used the wildcard syntax to provide autocomplete and google live type results with sphinx. You'd start typing "New " and it would offer "New York Times, New York Post" etc. It was fast enough to provide this with ajax.