# C++ framework for search and indexing like clucene

Tags: c++, indexing, search-engine

does anyone know some good alternatives for clucene as a search and indexing framework for c++ which is well documented and up to date?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its possible that I need to change some code of the engine for example to use an own distance measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Sphinx - http://sphinxsearch.com/.

> Sphinx is a free software search engine designed with indexing database content in mind. It currently supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, and ODBC-compliant databases as data sources natively. Other data sources can be indexed via pipe in a custom XML format. It is distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License version two or a proprietary license.

src: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_%28search_engine%29

This also could be useful for you:
[Comparison of full text search engine - Lucene, Sphinx, Postgresql, MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I would maybe like to have the opportunity to change the code of the framework like to using some own distance measure. Is that possible with Sphinx? That looks like it may be hard

Comment: @jstr This is GPL software so as long as you conform to license you could try to make some changes to code- if it is what you're asking for. I assume that it wont be easy though. If you mean that you want to somehow extend Sphinx, I do not know whether it is possible, or how. I have used it briefly some time ago and this was rather basic usage.

Comment: Hmm ok so I think I'll give that egyptian lady a chance ;-)