# Full text search engine lists and their performance for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, full-text-search, lucene.net

I'm looking for a full text search engine which is portable to be used in ASP.NET.

**Here is my scenario:** I have 40 millions of customer's names and I want to find their CustomerId by searching their names.
I know the MS-SQL Full Text Search could be a resonable solution, but due to its installation, licensing, and some DBO tasks, I'm wondering if there is another solution.

I've tested [Lucene.net](http://blogs.apache.org/lucenenet/), the insertion speed is very slow, so I've given up!

I also saw [hOOt](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224722/hOOt-full-text-search-engine) (I didn't test it yet).

**Question:** Is there any resource to see the comparison of full text search engines? Which is best for my needs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for .NET based engines, not RDBMS or Java based engines.