# full text search in java web applicatioin

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparison of full text search engine - Lucene, Sphinx, Postgresql, MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql)

I am doing a web project based on java. I am using postgresql as the database server.My question is how to do full text in my application.There are two options. they are apache lucene and sphinx search. but i haven't use them before. so what is the best option?

i have to consider following points
1. i have to do full text search through 20-50 tables.
2. this is an enterprise application

Comment: I'm not sure this question I'll be judged appropriate as it's an "opinion" question, but I've used lucene and it worked very well.

Comment: can i use it with postgresql?

Comment: A third option is to use PostgreSQL's built-in fulltext search features. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html . It's limited, but can perform extremely well.

Comment: Here's a post comparing the options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql

Comment: may i know,what do you mean by limited here. i searched it and it takes 20 ms to execute indexed query?