# Django filter custom look up

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

How can I add custom filtering to Django search?
currently lookup_expr='icontains' match the words that contains string.

Example:

I want to search the work "elephant". if i type `ele, phant`, then icontains works. But if i type `elepant (missed h)` then icontains wont return anything.

So I want to build the search text that matches similar word.
How can I do that in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "full text search". If you are using postgres database then [django has some native support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) for it. Otherwise, there is a huge branch of software devoted just to full text search out there, can start your journey [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql).