# Search inside JSON text books

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, search, full-text-search

I'm developing an app in Angular.

I have some text books, which I store in a JSON format. Each section of the book is composed of an object inside the JSON array, like this:

```
{
"Chapter": "Intro",
"Id": "1",
"Section_Body":"blah blah"
"Section_Title": "Something"
},
```

Each book is stored in a different JSON file.

I am trying to implement a full text search on these books, where a user could search for a word or a few words and find the results in the books (not just find if the exact text is included there).

What is the best and easiest way to do this?

Comment: Use a full-text search engine for that.

Comment: @Dekel Example?

Comment: Google? you can use this for a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql

Comment: function searchText(array, 'keyword') {
 transform(array: any[], keyword): any {
  if (array == null) {
    return null;
  }  
  return array.filter(function(obj) {
    if (args[1]) {
   return obj.Section_Body === keyword;
    }
    return array;
  }); 
 }
} Use above function to search text.

Comment: @PrashantMBhavsar this is not even close to full-text search.