# mysql select query (dictionary search)

Tags: mysql

I have a table and I want to get the row with the value that most closely resembles the searched text. For example if searched text is 'rakul' it should be able to select row with value 'rahul'

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a rich full text capabiliity. Try a dedicated [full text search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql)

Comment: Not an answer, but is your logic here "sounds like" or "looks like," or maybe both?

Comment: well looks like. if it was sounds like i could have used soundex function in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Just change the **Customers** value to your table name and the **FirstName** to what column you want to search and the **David** to your word want to search for it

```
  SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE FirstName LIKE '%David%';
```

Comment: well the other word is a variable (which is the word that search is for). so query would become something like SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE FirstName like '%<varaible name>%'; so even if i search for dabid it will not retrun the correct result(which is david)

Comment: yeah please read this examples , you will clearly understand how to use like for serach https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp