# Full-text search - should I pick dedicated search engine (SOLR, Elastic) or RDBMS one?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am working on my diploma exam with topic of Full-Text Search in Apache SOLR. Within the introduction, I should elaborate what are the purpose and advantages of Apache SOLR, i.e. why would one opt for Full-Text Search engine like SOLR instead of MySQL, for instance. Using literature like "SOLR in action (2013)" one would say it's rather easy to determine when to  use SOLR, ElasticSearch or something else, instead of MySQL - for that era. There is also this great question from 2010 on SO:
[Comparison of full text search engine - Lucene, Sphinx, Postgresql, MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql).
Alas, as great as it was around 2010, answers now seem painfully obsolete. E.g. "MySQL MyISAM table type supports Full-Text Search, but InnoDB does not".
Several years after this InnoDB also added Full-Text Search support.
Now, there are some articles that manage to shed some light on this, like
https://lucidworks.com/post/full-text-search-engines-vs-dbms/ which states that advantages of Full-Text Search systems are

> search speed, variety of indexing and querying options, ranking and relevancy capabilities...

Yet, there are lot of other articles stating things like

> MySQL Full-Text Search will now fit your needs in 80% of cases

etc, and it seems that over past 10 years MySql, MongoDB, PostgreSQL and other relational database Full-Text Search capability increased dramatically.

Yet, graph on https://db-engines.com/en/ranking_trend/system/Elasticsearch%3BMySQL%3BSolr shows that Full-Text Search engines are not losing popularity, but their usage is growing, and even SOLR that was losing pace steadily, now seems to be waking up.

So, there must be something to it? Is it that:

- SOLR, Elastic, Sphinx... are still considerably faster than their relational counterparts?
- there is larger variety of options, like advanced, customizable tokenization, faceting? Maybe better languages support?
- relational databases can't handle well enough search on very large number of documents?

etc.

In short, what would make you take Apache SOLR or Elastic nowadays, instead of MySQL or other relational database with their increased Full-Text search capabilities? Why are Apache SOLR and Elastic Search still that popular when using them requires another stack of resources and administration if you already have data in your relational or NoSQL database?

So the central question is:
If I have system that uses MySQL database for data storage, and I need to add full text search capabilities for one or several fields, to include fuzzy search (typos), synonyms, stemming, to handle relevancy and ranking in custom way, is it generally better to use MySQL FTS (so no need for another stack of resources and administration) or a dedicated full text search engine like Apache SOLR or Elastic search is significantly enough better at this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specialized indexing solutions like Apache Solr, ElasticSearch, Sphinx Search are usually faster than the built-in fulltext indexing of MySQL or GIST of PostreSQL, etc. The specialized solutions often have more features like stemming, more sophisticated searching including faceting, and also storing extra data in a "document" associated with the indexed text.

On the other hand, using one of those complementary solutions means extra complexity to copy data into the indexing solution. How frequently do you need to update the index? Is it efficient to update the index incrementally, or do you basically need to clobber the index and create a fresh index from your whole dataset?

Whereas using the builtin indexing features of your RDBMS have the advantage that the index is probably kept in sync with the most recent data updates automatically. And the search capabilities may be good enough for your needs. Keeping the index maintenance simple and automated has a lot of positive value.

Besides, any of the solutions, even a sub-optimal one, is orders of magnitude better than the naïve approach many developers use: `textcolumn LIKE '%keyword%'`

> what would make you take Apache SOLR or Elastic nowadays, instead of MySQL or other relational database with their increased Full-Text search capabilities?

Better performance, more sophisticated search support, and it helps to move those expensive search queries to a dedicated search engine, and lighten the load on your RDBMS.

Comment: Much appreciated. 
And for the record ```textcolumn LIKE '%keyword%'``` is just what is set as the reason for SOLR-like search engines in 2013. version of "SOLR in action", yet it seems that MySQL FTS has come a long way since.

Comment: I did update my slide deck about comparing fulltext indexing solutions, to include the InnoDB implementation. https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql

Comment: Oh mr Carwin, but now I see that it is very your slide deck that I read literally minutes before posting this question and it is one of the best  resources I managed to find on the topic indeed! I am sure I will refer to it in my work.